# Spring Social- Connect without having to constantly authorize the user

Tags: spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I have an application that needs to stream a specific users twitter data and search for specific hash-tag data then mass distribute an email, but if I'm understanding things correctly every time I want to connect, I have to redirect to an authorization page. All this should be in the background. Is there a way I can have the application authorize once, then always stream the data using spring social, if not, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth uses tokens that expire. So no matter what, your users will still have to periodically log in via Twitter and go through the OAuth process again to get a fresh token. They will only have to authorize your app the first time, so subsequently they should get sent right back to your app (assuming this is a Web app). You might want to look at using ReconnectFilter, again assuming you're making a Web app:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/social/connect/web/ReconnectFilter.html